# PHP / MYSQLI: Read row before while loop

Tags: php, mysqli, store, associative-array

I've got following code:

```
<html> //This is using bootstrap, but nevermind, has nothing todo with question...
<body>
  <?php
      echo "<div class=\"list-group\">".PHP_EOL;
      $connection = mysqli_connect('...');
      if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          die('Connection Error');
      }
      $connection->set_charset("utf8"); //$bid is a var declared before
      $getcom = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM hilde_comments WHERE Refer_ID LIKE '$bid' ORDER BY Comment_ID DESC LIMIT 10");
      if ($getcom->num_rows > 0) {
          while ($row = $getcom->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
              $getacc = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM hilde_accounts WHERE adress_id LIKE '$row["Account_adress"]'");
              if ($getacc->num_rows > 0) {
                  $accinf = $getacc->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                  echo "<div class=\"list-group-item\">".PHP_EOL;
                  echo "<h4 class=\"list-group-item-heading\"><a href='".$accinf["link"]."' alt=\"Click here!\">".$accinf["email"]."</a></h4>".PHP_EOL;
                  echo "<p class=\"list-group-item-text\">".$row["Comment"]."</p></div>".PHP_EOL;
              } else {
                  echo "Information ".$row["Account_UID"]." failed.";
              }

          }
          $getcom->close();
          $getacc->close();
          $connection->close();
          echo "</div>";
      } else {
          $getcom->close();
          $connection->close();
          echo("<div class=\"list-group-item list-group-item-danger\">Text not found</div>");
      }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, this will not work (as somebody pointed out in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060313/php-mysqli-theory-of-while-loop-to-loop-through-query-results)). But for continuing, I need the results of both queries for echoing, as you can see in my example snippet. How can I store the results of the first query and actually use them as ASSOC in my while loop?

Thanks in advance guys,

VicStudio

Comment: Aren't the results of your first query in the `$row` variable already ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet Yes it is, but i can´t start a second query while the first one is still active (and wasn´t closed yet)

Comment: Can you post your real code? I'd guess you are using `$row` in your second query and overwriting the first fetch. You also could probably do this all with 1 query and a `join`.

Comment: Open a second connection?

Comment: @chris85 It´s the real snippet now...

Comment: @ethrbunny I think that wouldn´t help the problem with 2 querys running at same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't use multiple queries. You do not need to finish processing one query before executing another.

```
$getcom = $connection->query("...");
while ($row = $getcom->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $getacc = $connection->query("...");
    while ($row2 = $getacc->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row2["Name"]." and ".$row["Adress"];
    }
}
```

**Edit** Now that the real code has been added, I can see that the problem is here:

```
$getacc = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM hilde_accounts WHERE adress_id LIKE '$row["Account_adress"]'");
```

You're mixing quotes. You're probably getting a mysqli error on that query (or a syntax error from PHP). You should **really** use a parameterized query for this, but if you *have* to use the variable this way, interrupt your string:

```
$getacc = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM hilde_accounts WHERE adress_id LIKE '" . $row["Account_adress"] . "'");
```

That will work, as long as there's no `'` in the address. Keep in mind that this kind of code is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen, please switch to using a parameterized query.

Comment: Whats a parameterized query?

Comment: Thanks! You helped a lot, not only in my problem but also in my webpage security system! :)